# How to add to cart Woocommerce Booking Product?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I need to adding to cart woocommerce booking product, if i writing this code, i have false
Or where normal documentation for this plugin?

global $woocommerce;
$added = $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id);

Answer (score 0):

As, per my understanding i think bookable products meant to be book only.
For that what you need to do is use this piece of code to do this pragmatically.

```
create_wc_booking( $product_id, $new_booking_data = array(), $status = 'confirmed', $exact = false )
```

1 Product ID: The id of the bookable product which you are creating a new booking for.
2.New Booking data: Array of booking data.
3.Status: Status of the new booking. Valid statuses include: ‘unpaid’, ‘pending’, ‘confirmed’, ‘cancelled’, ‘complete’
4.Exact: true or false – If false, the function will look for the next available slot after your start date, if the date you tried to book is unavailable.

Comment: when i trying this method, it creates a booking, but not adding to cart, i need adding to cart so that later you can pay for it on the checkout page

Comment: Just posted another answer, Please try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// add the below code in a in functions.php of your theme.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', array( $this, 'wdm_add_cities_to_cart' ), 11, 2 );

// the function accepts two parameters, the cart data and the product id
public function wdm_add_cities_to_cart( $cart_item_meta, $product_id ) {
    // let's consider that the user is logged in
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if( 0 != $user_id)
    {
        // set the values as bookings meta
        $cart_item_meta['booking']['From'] = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'FROM', true );
        $cart_item_meta['booking']['To'] = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'TO', true );  
    }
    return $cart_item_meta;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, which was about how to add a WC Booking Product to the cart programmatically.